# Does a subscription offerered from my private server to see a content will be considered as In App Purchase when transferring a app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

this is a specific question related to "Transferring the App". I have made an app which makes the user pay for content to see through my sever (It has payment gateway enabled). Now I want to transfer the app to another party. As I was reading the criteria to transfer the app, I found a point which states, "The app can’t offer (or have previously offered) In-App Purchase subscriptions: auto-renewable, free, or non-renewing" in "Criteria for Transferring an App" in the below reference

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

How ever I am confused is my **content subscription** will be judged as **In App purchase**.

Comment: If you don't use in-app purchases then this doesn't apply

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't use In App Purchase of Apple but I ask user to subscribe to contents through my payment gateway. will it be considered as in app purchase?

Comment: You can't offer alternate subscription/payment methods in your app.  You can allow the user to pay via your website but you can't link to that website from your app.  The only 'in-app' purchase option that is available is via Apple.  Any other type of purchase is out-of-app.  Also note the capitalisation on Apple's conditions - they are referring specifically to their in-app purchases

Comment: I am really sorry however I did not get you. Lets suppose I have a video which resides at my server, when a user install a app,that app displays that video information and show the video info to user, user click on "Buy" and we have section for "Credit Card Details" to enter and that we send to our server to make hat payment to happen from their card and subsequently, after that, user can see that video. is it allowed ? and will this be considered as In app purchase (regarding Transfer app)?

Comment: that app will not be approved by Apple because it offers In-App purchases via another gateway.  All in-app purchases must use Apple's framework.  Refer to section 11.2 - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies